# Powershell Try Catch for detecting usb enumeration during copy

Tags: powershell, try-catch

```
while($true)
{
try 
{
copy-item C:\Users\...\Desktop\1gb F:\ -recurse -force -ea Stop
} 
catch 
{
echo "Drive not found"
}
}
```

Here I am able to catch the exception and display "Drive not found"

But my question is once the drive destination is available I want the copy to continue. Is it possible to do that?

All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this help you:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$RetryCount = 0; $MaxTries = 5; $Completed = $false

$Source = 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\1gb'
$Destination = 'F:\'

while (-not $Completed) {
    Try {
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $Source -Destination $Destination -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        $Completed = $true
    }
    Catch {
        if ($RetryCount -ge $MaxTries) {
            Write-Verbose 'Drive not found'
            throw "Drive not found Source '$($Source)' > '$($Destination)': $($Global:Error[0].Exception.Message)"
        } 
        else {
            Write-Verbose "Drive not found, retrying in 5 seconds."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            $RetryCount++
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially it retries every 5 seconds, and if it fails for the 6th time it will throw an error and stop all actions. You can modify it to minutes, hours, .. to fit your needs.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! Thanks for the help. But this snippet works when i eject the drive manually but when i insert it back its still saying "drive not found". The powershell ise is not getting the refreshed information when i put back the drive!

Comment: You could also run the above code to check for presence of the USB drive. This code can be usefull coming from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/87aa06e9-77dd-4246-bbfe-93a1eaa927ed/how-to-get-the-drive-letter-of-a-usb-drive-by-its-name): If you know the USB drive label you can use `Get-PSDrive | Where { $_.Description -eq 'BOOTME' } | Select Root` else use `Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk" | where { $_.driveType -eq 2 } | Select volumename,deviceid`.